# Admob native ads of UnifiedNativeAdView are not clickable in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, admob, native-ads, unifiednativeadview

I faced a strange bug with admob native ads. Everything works fine except that I cannot find url value for an ads on callback and that UnifiedNativeAdView is not clickable, even button inside don't go anywhere as I use admob templates.

Here is the XML view code:

```
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView
               android:paddingTop="8dp"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/native_ad_view"
               android:background="#000000"
               android:elevation="20dp">

                 <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/native_ad_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                           <TextView
                             style="@style/AdAttribution"
                             android:id="@+id/native_ad_attribution"
                             android:visibility="gone"/>

                           <LinearLayout
                              android:id="@+id/native_ad_inside_layout"
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="0dp"
                              android:layout_gravity="center"
                              android:layout_weight="1"
                              android:orientation="horizontal"
                              android:visibility="gone">

                                  <ImageView
                                     android:id="@+id/ad_app_icon"
                                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                     android:layout_gravity="center"
                                     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                     android:maxWidth="85dp"
                                     android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                                  <TextView
                                     android:id="@+id/ad_headline"
                                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                     android:layout_gravity="center"
                                     android:layout_weight="1"
                                     android:maxLines="3"
                                     android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                     android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                     android:textSize="16sp"
                                     android:textStyle="bold" />

                                  <Button
                                     android:id="@+id/ad_call_to_action"
                                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                     android:layout_gravity="center"
                                     android:gravity="center"
                                     android:maxWidth="50dp"
                                     android:maxLines="3"
                                     android:textSize="12sp"
                                   />
                           </LinearLayout>

                  </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView>
```

Code of *Viewholder*:

```
    inner class TripViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

       val adView: UnifiedNativeAdView = view.native_ad_view as UnifiedNativeAdView
       var layoutView: LinearLayout = view.native_ad_layout
       var insideLayoutView: LinearLayout = view.native_ad_inside_layout
       var attributionView: TextView = view.native_ad_attribution

       var headlineView: TextView = view.ad_headline
       var callToActionView: Button = view.ad_call_to_action
       var iconView: ImageView = view.ad_app_icon
   }
```

Code of *onBindViewHolder*:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {


    val item = mValues[position]

    if (item.nativeAd == null) {
        return
    }

    if (item.nativeAd!!.headline == null) {
        return
    }

    holder.attributionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.insideLayoutView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.headlineView.text = item.nativeAd!!.headline

    if (item.nativeAd!!.callToAction == null) {
        holder.callToActionView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    } else {
        holder.callToActionView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        (holder.callToActionView as Button).text = item.nativeAd!!.callToAction
    }

    if (item.nativeAd!!.icon == null) {
        holder.iconView.visibility = View.GONE
    } else {
        (holder.iconView as ImageView).setImageDrawable(item.nativeAd!!.icon.drawable)
        holder.iconView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    // Assign native ad object to the native view.
    holder.adView.setNativeAd(item.nativeAd!!)

}
```

And this is where I call *adLoader*. I call it in the background using *BroadcastReceiver*:

```
      fun loadNativeAds(context: Context, listener: MyTripsContent.ContentEventsListener?) {
            if (!adList.isEmpty()) {
                return
            }
            try {
                var unitId: String? = ""
                lateinit var adLoader: AdLoader
                //test key
                unitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110"
                adLoader = AdLoader.Builder(context, unitId)
                        .forUnifiedNativeAd { ad: UnifiedNativeAd ->
                            // Show the ad.
                            adList.add(ad)
                            if (adList.size == 5) {
                                listener?.onLoadedDocuments(0)
                            }
                        }
                        .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Int) {
                                // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.
                                if (!adLoader.isLoading) {
                                }
                            }

                            override fun onAdClicked() {
                                super.onAdClicked()
                            }
                        })
                        .withNativeAdOptions(
                                NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                                        // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
                                        // used here to specify individual options settings.
                                        .build()
                        )
                        .build()
                adLoader.loadAds(AdRequest.Builder().build(), 5)
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

So as I mentioned ads work well but they are not clickable. I'm not sure if this is a bug from admob, or my code or something I am missing. I think other developers will face the same issue in the future, so it would be good to solve it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So due to lack of detailed documentation and examples I found I was missing one line of code. Many other examples do not have this line also. I only added one line in *onBindViewHolder*

From this:

```
if (item.nativeAd!!.callToAction == null) {
    holder.callToActionView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
} else {
    holder.callToActionView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    (holder.callToActionView as Button).text = item.nativeAd!!.callToAction
}
```

to this:

```
if (item.nativeAd!!.callToAction == null) {
    holder.callToActionView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
} else {
    holder.callToActionView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    (holder.callToActionView as Button).text = item.nativeAd!!.callToAction
    holder.adView.callToActionView = (holder.callToActionView as Button)
}
```

That means I needed to attach my button as callToActionView

Comment: In case someone needs this in java: "adView.setCallToActionView(button);"